# Capture swift closure value in function

Tags: swift, closures

May be this is very simple but i am not able to figure it out.

Please let me know if it is correct way or not

in my tableview cell I have following closure

```
public var btnBulbTappedClo:((CommentCell) -> (Void))?
```

and I call it with

```
@IBAction func btnBulbTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.btnBulbTappedClo?(self)
}
```

In my view controller cellForRow method

I call func  btnBulbTapped with returned closure by cell

```
self.btnBulbTapped(cell.btnBulbTapped)
```

Code compiles correctly but I don't know how to access cell ?

```
 func btnBulbTapped (_ clou :((CommentCell) -> Void)?) {
        // how to access `CommentCell`   object here
  }
```

Comment: Aren't you doing something redundant in your `btnBulbTapped(_ sender: Any)` method? You care sending the same method to the other `btnBulbTapped` when you could just do the same thing here. What is the purpose of using closure? I think what you need can be easily achieved by delegation.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are not using this correctly, if I understand you you have a `UITableViewCell` subclass that defines `public var btnBulbTappedClo:((CommentCell) -> (Void))?` and when a button inside of this cell is tapped closure should be invoked...

Not sure what you were going with your `func btnBulbTapped` function. You would use this like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //..dequeue your cell
    cell.btnBulbTapped = {commentCell in 
        //here you have access to comment Cell inside of a closure
    }
}
```

Based on your question in the comments you have 2 options:

1) just call a function from the given closure

```
cell.btnBulbTapped = {[weak self] commentCell in 
    self?.btnPressed(commentCell)
}

func btnPressed(_ cell: CommentCell) {
    //do whats needed here with the cell
}
```

2) Define a protocol

```
protocol CommentCellDelegate {
    func didSelectCell(_ cell: CommentCell)
}
```

Add a delegate variable to your `CommentCell` class and invoke the delegate in the `IBAction` method:

```
weak var commentDelegate: CommentCellDelegate?

@IBAction func btnBulbTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    commentDelegate.didSelectCell(self)  
}

//to be sure set delegate to nil in prepareForReuse inside your cell subclass

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    commentDelegate = nil
}
```

Assing your `controller` as delegate to each cell

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //..dequeue your cell
    cell.commentDelegate = self
}

func didSelectCell(_ cell: CommentCell) {
    //do what's needed here
}
```

Comment: I know that way. but issue is The CommentCell is used in header as well as tableview cell. So I don't want duplicate code  like  `cell.btnBulbTapped = {commentCell in` in both function. So I want to create function that can handle that closure